# Encoding with ampersand jquery / json / mvc

Tags: jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, encoding

I have in my SQL Server database strings stored with additional `&amp` sign 
like `Black &amp; White`. I send this via MVC controller with JSON, and extract this to front end with jQuery. It ends up being sent in JSON as `Black &amp; White`, but displayed in the UI without the `&amp` so `Black&White`.

When user selects `Black&White` in the UI, this literal value gets sent back to controller as parameter, so it can be looked up in db. The obvious problem is that I don't have `Black&White` in db, only `Black &amp; White` so result of query is none. What options would be there?

Comment: You have to do `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(uri);` that will give you `&` from `&amp`

Comment: thank you, I will try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use

```
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(uri);
```

that will give you `&` from `&amp`

Comment: I need & to be displayed on the frontend without &amp, so at which stage do you see this to be added? And what would be the uri, I'm not passing uri as parameter at any time.